# osx - Playing youtube videos in terminal as text using mpv or mplayer with libcaca or aalib?

Tags: macos, youtube, video-streaming, homebrew, mplayer

I installed via `homebrew`:

```
brew install mplayer mpv libcaca aalib
```

to try to play videos as text in my terminal. Using `mplayer`, I tried aa:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urxk4mveLCw -o - | mplayer -cache 64000 -vo aa -
```

and also caca:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urxk4mveLCw -o - | CACA_DRIVER=ncurses mplayer -cache 64000 -vo caca -
```

however, both give the following error:

```
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.
```

Trying again with `mpv`:

```
mpv "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC83NA5tAGE" -vo caca
mpv "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC83NA5tAGE" -vo aa
```

Which outputs:

```
09:00 $ mpv "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC83NA5tAGE" -vo aalib
Playing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC83NA5tAGE
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) 'DASH audio' (opus) (external)
[vo] Video output aalib not found!
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.
Video: no video

Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
✘-2 ~
```

When looking at the man page for `mpv`, I find:

```
   caca   Color  ASCII art video output driver that works on a text console.

          NOTE:
             This driver is a joke.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correctly watch the youtube videos in the terminal?

Thanks.

P.S If it makes a difference, here is my `screenfetch` information:

```
OS: 64bit Mac OS X 10.9.5 13F1603
Kernel: x86_64 Darwin 13.4.0
DE: Aqua
WM: Quartz Compositor
WM Theme: Blue
GPU: Intel Iris
```

Also I am using `iterm2` as my terminal, but I also have `xterm` via `xquartz`, and the normal `terminal`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

caca is not installed with mpv by default, you will need to set it as an option flag.

You can reinstall this with caca with

```
brew reinstall mpv --with-libcaca
```

or if you are installing from fresh

```
brew install mpv --with-libcaca
```

Now running

```
mpv --vo=help
```

Outputs the following

```
Available video outputs:
  opengl         : Extended OpenGL Renderer
  null           : Null video output
  image          : Write video frames to image files
  caca           : libcaca
  opengl-hq      : Extended OpenGL Renderer (high quality rendering preset)
```

So you can see that caca is now available to be used. Then simply run your command to play your chosen video in terminal.

```
mpv "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC83NA5tAGE" -vo caca
```

Comment: Yup it worked perfectly, except I needed the `-ytdl` flag. Thanks!!

Comment: no luck: `Error: invalid option: --with-libcaca`

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't have caca/aa driver compiled in mpv/mplayer; check:

```
mpv --vo=help
mplayer --vo=help
```

if they don't list caca, you should try to compile mpv (or mplayer) from source.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was up there in Google's results for playing YouTube videos but only audio. In 2024, it seems libcaca isn't necessary. The option to play without video is already built-in via the "null" video output:

```
mpv --vo=help
Available video outputs:
  libmpv           render API for libmpv
  gpu              Shader-based GPU Renderer
  gpu-next         Video output based on libplacebo
  null             Null video output
  image            Write video frames to image files
  tct              true-color terminals
  kitty            Kitty terminal graphics protocol
```

So just do

```
mpv "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-2TaN77gD4" -vo null
```